# Change table row color when drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 5 different colors: for ex. (1)red, (2)orange, (3)blue, (4)yellow, (5)and green. These colors will only color my top 5 data. If I drag and drop data to number 2 it must be color orange and so on .... How to implement it using css or js?

Comment: Enter your HTML code first

Comment: **Show us some code** and tell us what you're using e.g. jQuery UI's `draggable()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with this idea:

```
<style>
    #sort-handler:hover { opacity:0.1 }
    .color {
        width: 7px;
    }
    tbody tr:nth-child(1) td.color {
        background-color: #3366CC;
    }
    tbody tr:nth-child(2) td.color {
        background-color: #DC3912;
    }
    tbody tr:nth-child(3) td.color {
        background-color: #FF9928;
    }
    tbody tr:nth-child(4) td.color {
        background-color: #0F9627;
    }
    tbody tr:nth-child(5) td.color {
        background-color: #990099;
    }
</style>

<table>
    <thead>
        .......
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="color"></td>
            <td><img src="arrow.gif" style="cursor:move;" class="sort-handle"
                    onmousedown="event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false"></td>
            <td>
                ......
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
    //Your drag and drop js
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

To colour table rows, try this:

Assuming you have a table that's something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>Some text! 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Some text! 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Some text! 3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Some text! 4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Some text! 5</td></tr>
</table>
```

Then, use CSS to style these rows:

```
table tr:nth-child(1){ background: red;    } /* colour the first row "red" */
table tr:nth-child(2){ background: orange; } /* colour the second row "orange" */
table tr:nth-child(3){ background: blue;   } /* etc... */
table tr:nth-child(4){ background: yellow; }
table tr:nth-child(5){ background: green;  }
```

**[Result](http://fiddle.jshell.net/bAYuU/)**